# Qual a função de StandardScaler() do Sklearn

Tags: python, redes-neurais, sklearn

O código abaixo encontrei no link [Classifying the Iris Data Set with Keras](https://janakiev.com/notebooks/keras-iris/).
E gostaria de entender qual a utilidade de **StandardScaler()**, diz que é importante para convergência?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

iris = load_iris()
X = iris['data']
y = iris['target']
names = iris['target_names']
feature_names = iris['feature_names']

# One hot encoding
enc = OneHotEncoder()
Y = enc.fit_transform(y[:, np.newaxis]).toarray()

# Scale data to have mean 0 and variance 1 
# which is importance for convergence of the neural network
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Split the data set into training and testing
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(
    X_scaled, Y, test_size=0.5, random_state=2)

n_features = X.shape[1]
n_classes = Y.shape[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StandardScalerque implementa a TransformerAPI para calcular a média e o desvio padrão em um conjunto de treinamento, de modo a poder reaplicar posteriormente a mesma transformação no conjunto de teste. Portanto, esta classe é adequada para uso nas etapas iniciais de um sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline
você pode ler toda a documentaçâo dessa biblioteca neste site: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html